# Jmeter --- ZIP File downloaded partially when tested with more number of threads using Jmeter

Tags: file, download, jmeter, load, performance-testing

so I am running a jmeter test which simply sends http request to server and downloads file of 168 MB. file is hosted on amazonaws.

File download works fine up to some number of users, all users are able to download file successfully with 168 MB size.

but if I test with more threads like 50 or more, all users are downloading file partially. I.e. some has 66 MB, some has 5 MB, some has more than 100 MB, etc.

but none of user could download file fully of 168 MB.

We tried to observed windows log and server log, but nothing suspicious there.

What could be technical reason behind this ? or how can I achieve this test ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check you don't have any timeouts defined at [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) level (or better at [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

   [image]
2. Tick `Save response as MD5 hash` - it will allow to reduce the number of resources JMeter allocates to save the whole file. You will be able to check the integrity of the downloaded file using [MD5Hex Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion)

   [image]
3. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) in particular:

   - [run you test in non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
   - disable all the [listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) during the test run

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. I cross checked above but it still did not solve my problem. however, I have below observations:

1. Jmeter keeps 168 MB file in memory only and does not write to disk.
2. because of this, if I go with more users heap memory is getting full and terminating the tests.

is there any setting to tell jmeter to write data in disk and keep them in memory for long ?

currently it looks like Jmeter won't write to disk unless all 168 MB of 1 file is downloaded.